# Finding a good variable substitution for a double intergral

Tags: multivariable-calculus

I want to compute the following integral

$$
\iint_D{(x-y) dxdy}
$$

where D is the triangle contained within these points: (0,0), (-2,1) and (-1,3).

The lines that connect the the points form the following equations:

$$
  \begin{equation}
    \begin{cases}
      y-2x=5 \\
      y+\frac12x=0 \\
      y+3x=0
    \end{cases}
  \end{equation}
$$

In the example solution I have they do the substitution $u=2y+x$ and $v=y+3x$. I tried with the substitution $u=y-2x$ and $v=y+3x$ and ended up with the wrong answer.

What choices in variable substitutions do I have here? What's the "thought process"? Do you have any tips to finding a "good one"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that one way to get good at finding substitutions to integrals is just to practise them and identify what techniques can be used and which are/aren't suitable. Sometimes it's more of a matter of recgonising an integrand that looks like a specific identity can be used with it.

Multiple integrals are trickier than single variable integrals, because there is often a challenge in setting up the limits of the integrals over each variable, as you need to visualise how they change across the domain you've considered. What limits did you use?

Comment: [This graph](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%7Bv%3D-u%3B+u%3D5%3B+v%3D0%7D) shows the area I considered with my substitution. So the inner integral would have the limits [-u, 0] (with respect to dv) and the outer [0, 5] (with respect to du).

I got the sense that the only substitution possible in this example is the one that was chosen in the example solution, because I always ended up with the wrong answer otherwise, but I doesn't really make sense to me. Maybe I just miscalculated with my own substitutions?

Comment: @haeger Your substitution is as easy as that suggested. The limits look right. You must have done some miscalculation. Didn't you forget to multiply by the Jacobian determinant for the (inverse) substitution?

Comment: @A.G. No, but I must've done something else wrong then. I'll have a look at it again. Thanks!

Comment: Marking this as the solution, as it confirmed that I made a mistake.

Answer (score 0):

By [Green's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Green%27s_theorem),
$$ \iint_D (x-y)\,dx\,dy = \frac{1}{2}\int_{\partial D}\left( x^2\,dy + y^2\,dx\right). $$
Along the first side $S_1$ from $(0,0)$ to $(-2,1)$ we have $x=-2y$ or $y=-\frac{1}{2}x$, hence:
$$ \int_{S_1}\left( x^2\,dy + y^2\,dx\right) = \int_{0}^{1}4y^2\,dy + \int_{0}^{-2}\frac{x^2}{4}\,dx = \frac{2}{3}$$
and by doing the same for the other two sides we easily get the answer.

Comment: Didn't really answer the question, but this seems to really simplify the calculation. I'll have to look into Green's theorem... Thanks!